# How do I stop this message?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, launchd

I’m on a Mac running OS X 10.6.x and I’m seeing this `launchd` error message repeated constantly in `Console.app`:

How can I stop this error message?

> 3/3/12 3:35:03.002 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.503:
>   (com.hp.help.tocgenerator) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10
>   seconds

Comment: Where do you see it? While doing what?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of com.apple.launchd.peruser errors in my log?](http://superuser.com/questions/194094/how-do-i-get-rid-of-com-apple-launchd-peruser-errors-in-my-log)

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: It is seen in Console.app as the standard output/error of a process in Mac OS X. He is likely seeing a repeated barrage of these messages from `launchd`, which is the part of OS X that handles launch agent and launch daemon services.

Comment: @iglvzx: This question is not a duplicate. The only thing this question has in common with that one is that it happens to involve `launchd` jobs. `launchd` is a public API Apple provides in Mac OS X to implement on-demand services: millions of developers can and do use it to implement services in their applications. The cause of all the error messages logged to console on behalf of a `launchd` job are going to be specific to the product that is using the API, not to the API itself. In this case, it's HP software.

Comment: Why the hell was this closed? If this question was so "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, [or] overly broad" then how was I able to come up with an exact solution for it? Please reopen this. Sorry, but if you know nothing about the tags in this question (`osx`, `mac`, and `launcd`), then please refrain from making a judgement about how "unclear" this question might be. It's perfectly clear to me. Every single word in that quoted error message is full of information.

Comment: @NSGod no need to be harsh. We can always reopen if the voters choose so

Comment: @SimonSheehan and others: sorry, that was out of line. I misunderstood what “closed” meant, mistakenly thinking the question could no longer be improved, which is of course not the case.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like it is being produced by some component of the HP software for your printer/scanner/multi-function device. (All `launchd` jobs are identified by a label, which is generally a reverse-DNS formatted string of the developer (see [CFBundleIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-102070-TPXREF105) for more info). In this case, it's hp.com).

[UPDATED]:
Okay, after a google search of that bundle identifier, I came across this [PhotoSmart C4280 repeating error messages in system.log](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Mac-Printing-and-Scanning/PhotoSmart-C4280-repeating-error-messages-in-system-log/td-p/413203) thread in HP's forums.

Basically, the reason for the issue is whoever wrote the HP software not really understanding how to implement a `launchd` LaunchAgent properly.

I wrote an AppleScript script to help automate the process of unloading the old launchd job, updating the plist file, and loading the new job:

[HP com.hp.help.tocgenerator Helper.app](http://www.markdouma.com/developer/HPcom.hp.help.tocgeneratorHelper.zip) (.zip file, ~29 KB)

Here's the code if you're interested:

```
if existsFile(":Library:LaunchAgents:com.hp.help.tocgenerator.plist") then
    set plistFileContentsString to (do shell script "/bin/cat /Library/LaunchAgents/com.hp.help.tocgenerator.plist")
    if (plistFileContentsString contains "LaunchOnlyOnce") then
        display alert "It looks like your \"com.hp.help.tocgenerator.plist\"
              has already been helped." buttons "Quit" default button "Quit"
        quit
    else
        set ourPlistPath to POSIX path of (path to resource "com.hp.help.tocgenerator.plist")
        do shell script "/bin/launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/com.hp.help.tocgenerator.plist;
 /bin/rm -f /Library/LaunchAgents/com.hp.help.tocgenerator.plist;
 /usr/bin/ditto --noqtn " & 
 quoted form of ourPlistPath &
   " /Library/LaunchAgents/com.hp.help.tocgenerator.plist;
 /usr/sbin/chown 0:0 /Library/LaunchAgents/com.hp.help.tocgenerator.plist;
 /bin/launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.hp.help.tocgenerator.plist"
 with administrator privileges
    end if
else
    display alert "Sorry, you don't appear to have the applicable
      HP software installed." buttons "Quit" default button "Quit"
    quit
end if
```

You should be able to run that AppleScript to alleviate the issue.